# Promisify Joi: compile is undefined

Tags: express, joi

I want to promisify Joi.validate.

The original function is:

```
Joi.validate(message, schema, (err, success) => {})
```

I tried to do:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const validate = Promise.promisify(Joi.validate);
```

And I call with:

```
validate(message, schema)
.then(() => console.log('ok'))
.catch(err => console.log('ERRRR', err.message));
```

But i receive this error:

```
Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined
```

Do you know how I can achieve it ?
Thank you

Comment: share full error stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that context is lost during promisification. So try this:

```
const validate = Promise.promisify(Joi.validate).bind(Joi);
validate(message, schema)
  .then(() => console.log('ok'))
  .catch(err => console.log('ERRRR', err.message));
```

Or this:

```
const pJoi = Promise.promisifyAll(Joi);
pJoi
  .validate(message, schema)
  .then(() => console.log('ok'))
  .catch(err => console.log('ERRRR', err.message));
```